# Trying to make a forum using Bootstrap. Code won't work. Any ideas?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

there!

So, I stumbled over this website (http://bootstrap.snipplicious.com/snippet/8/forum), where I found a Bootstrap template for a forum. I copy/pasted the HTML and CSS code, but it doesn't look exactly like on the page. Can anyone tell me why?

Snippet, added.

```css
.forum.table > tbody > tr > td {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.forum .fa {
    width: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}

.forum.table th.cell-stat {
    width: 6em;
}

.forum.table th.cell-stat-2x {
    width: 14em;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div class="container" style="margin-top: 35px">
  <div class="page-header page-heading">
    <h1 class="pull-left">Forums</h1>
    <ol class="breadcrumb pull-right where-am-i">
      <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
      <li class="active">List of topics</li>
    </ol>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <p class="lead">This is the right place to discuss any ideas, critics, feature requests and all the ideas regarding our website. Please follow the forum rules and always check FAQ before posting to prevent duplicate posts.</p>
  <table class="table forum table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="cell-stat"></th>
        <th>
          <h3>Important</h3>
        </th>
        <th class="cell-stat text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm">Topics</th>
        <th class="cell-stat text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm">Posts</th>
        <th class="cell-stat-2x hidden-xs hidden-sm">Last Post</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-question fa-2x text-primary"></i></td>
        <td>
          <h4><a href="#">Frequently Asked Questions</a><br><small>Some description</small></h4>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a href="#">9 542</a></td>
        <td class="text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a href="#">89 897</a></td>
        <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">by <a href="#">John Doe</a><br><small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 3 months ago</small></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-exclamation fa-2x text-danger"></i></td>
        <td>
          <h4><a href="#">Important changes</a><br><small>Category description</small></h4>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a href="#">6532</a></td>
        <td class="text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a href="#">152123</a></td>
        <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">by <a href="#">Jane Doe</a><br><small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 1 years ago</small></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="table forum table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="cell-stat"></th>
        <th>
          <h3>Suggestions</h3>
        </th>
        <th class="cell-stat text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm">Topics</th>
        <th class="cell-stat text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm">Posts</th>
        <th class="cell-stat-2x hidden-xs hidden-sm">Last Post</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-heart fa-2x text-primary"></i></td>
        <td>
          <h4><a href="#">More more more</a><br><small>Category description</small></h4>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a href="#">6532</a></td>
        <td class="text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a href="#">152123</a></td>
        <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">by <a href="#">Jane Doe</a><br><small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 3 months ago</small></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-magic fa-2x text-primary"></i></td>
        <td>
          <h4><a href="#">Haha</a><br><small>Category description</small></h4>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a href="#">6532</a></td>
        <td class="text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a href="#">152123</a></td>
        <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">by <a href="#">Jane Doe</a><br><small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 1 years ago</small></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="table forum table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="cell-stat"></th>
        <th>
          <h3>Open discussion</h3>
        </th>
        <th class="cell-stat text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm">Topics</th>
        <th class="cell-stat text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm">Posts</th>
        <th class="cell-stat-2x hidden-xs hidden-sm">Last Post</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="4" class="center">No topics have been added yet.</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: You need the bootstrap libs

Comment: Yup you didnt add the bootstrap CSS/JS files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add bootstrap to your page so it loads the css and js files necessary. You can reference it directly like this:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

And the javascript:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

More info here: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Comment: don't forget to mark the answer as correct, for future people reading the site

Comment: @bruno_cw I think you should give some times to OP to accept answer which is the best.

Comment: sure, by all means, i just said it since he commented that the answer worked